# Detect the programming language

Tags: java, syntax

Can anyone please tell me what is this coding language? It has similar structure to Java but I cannot understand.

```
class Sample {
    String student;
    @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "${student}";
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Sample s = new Sample();
          s.student = "Joe"
          System.out.println(s.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think its not Java?

Comment: because it doesnot have semicolons in some statements and it has return "${student}" in toString function

Comment: It's Java with two syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is valid in [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/)... and print "Joe" on standard output.

Comment: I thought so but i am not able to compile that in ideone :(

Comment: Hey thanks! I tried to compile that in another compiler(Tutorials point). it is running

Comment: Funny, it [works for me](https://ideone.com/5OOIdo)...

Comment: @Reimeus, the missing semicolon at the end of `s.student = "Joe"` maybe automatically added on that sandbox.

Comment: Why would it do that? It knows how to handle Groovy

Comment: Oops. Sorry I was referring to Java :)

Comment: actually I tested it on ideone without capitalization of class name. instead of "Sample" i was doing "sample". That is why it wasn't running for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is Java, no discussion on this.

But 2 errors :

```
class Sample {
    String student;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return student;   //<------------------ and not "${student}"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         s.student = "Joe";  //<---------------- don't forget ';'
    }
}
```

First error is intuitive, I mean you can `return "${student};` it will print it, but it's not what the user wanted to do, quite sure

Comment: The `"${student}"` is technically not an error. Agreed for the semicolon for Java.